# iOS Safari Web RTC Streaming quality

Tags: ios, video, safari, video-streaming, webrtc

I am trying to stream HD video from the smartphone's camera via WebRTC in the browser.

(I am using Wowza as media server on the backend.)

This is working, and produces good quality on Android, but on iOS, the quality seems to be really bad and blurry.

I am testing this on a very fast internet connection, so this should not be the issue.

I am assuming that I somehow need to adjust the SDP settings, but setting AS and TIAS to high values doesn't seem to do anything really.

Oh, iOS is using h264.

So my question is: is there a setting I'm missing or is WebRTC on iOS / Safari currently not configurable in a way to use higher bandwidth?

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing I would check before blaming the connection is check what resolution you're getting out of the camera.

Comment: Yes, the resolution is HD.